# pgfplots: correct rounding problems

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I had a problem with disappearing marker as the data sum up to more than 100 while xmax was set to 100. See [pgfplots: node near coords missing due to rounding problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294582/pgfplots-node-near-coords-missing-due-to-rounding-problems).

As written in the answer to the cited question I tried to avoid the problem by normalizing the value to 100. But this lead to (much smaller) rounding errors in previously correct rows and now the marker disappear there. See the following example. Before the normalisation the column F ist affected, after the column B.

How can I in a **reliable** way avoid this rounding problem? Or at least get a clear error message. I have quite a number of this plots and I don't want to have to check them all the time for missing markers.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{
 my stackbar plot/.style={
             xbar stacked,
             xmin=0,xmax=100,
             symbolic y coords={A,B,C,D,E,F,G},
             ytick=data,
             nodes near coords={xxx},}}

\begin{document}
 \pgfplotstableread[col sep=space]{
 text   --  -    +       ++
 A      0.0 1.7 13.8    84.5
 B      0.0 0.6 20.1    79.3
 C      0.0 1.9 13.2    84.9
 D      0.0 1.6 27.9    70.5
 E      1.3 3.9 19.5    75.3
 F      0.0 1.4 15.0    83.7
 G      0.3 1.7 24.8    73.2
 }\data


\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\thisrow{--}+\thisrow{-}+\thisrow{+}+\thisrow{++}}]{sum}\data %
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/copy=--]{--o}\data
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/copy=-]{-o}\data
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/copy=+]{+o}\data
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/copy=++]{++o}\data
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={100/\thisrow{sum}*\thisrow{--o}}]{--}\data
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={100/\thisrow{sum}*\thisrow{-o}}]{-}\data
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={100/\thisrow{sum}*\thisrow{+o}}]{+}\data
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={100/\thisrow{sum}*\thisrow{++o}}]{++}\data
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\thisrow{--}+\thisrow{-}+\thisrow{+}+\thisrow{++}}]{sumnew}\data

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={text,sum}   ,precision=10,columns/text/.style={string type}]\data \quad
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={text,sumnew},precision=10,columns/text/.style={string type}]\data 

%\pgfplotstablesave{\data}{pgfplotstempout.dat}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my stackbar plot]
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{--o},y=text] {\data};
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{-o}, y=text] {\data};
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{+o}, y=text] {\data};
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{++o}, y=text] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my stackbar plot]
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{--},y=text] {\data};
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{-}, y=text] {\data};
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{+}, y=text] {\data};
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{++}, y=text] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way using [`\usepackage{xintexpr}`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint):

- `\xinttheiexpr [d] ...\relax` produces a fixed point number with `d` digits after decimal mark, where `d` is a number `d =1, 2, ...`. It *rounds* the exactly computed result.
- `\xinttheexpr trunc(..., d)\relax` does the same but rather than rounding, it *truncates*. (Sorry for dubious syntax with `i` for rounding, and no `i` for truncating, what is happening is that some `\xinttheiexpr [d,trunc] ... \relax` should be implemented, I am stymied by what to choos as syntax because I don't want it to verbose, thought of `[d↓]`...).

We can use this in particular in locations where things working by pure expansion are allowed, as `\xinttheexpr, \xinttheiexpr` are f-expandable. (see the `xint` doc for what that means exactly).

<sub>Here are some comments which nobody even the author can understand now, even after some edit to make them less verbose.</sub>

<sub>In the summation for `sumnew` we are adding 4 numbers which have been rounded. Each (fixed-point) rounding introduced an absolute error at most `5 10^-7`, hence we have an error in the exact sum which is at most `2 10^-6 = 0.02 10^-4`. If we round that now to 4 digits, we have possible error of `0.52 10^-4`. Which means that it may not be the correct rounding of the exact sum, but `off by 1` for the unit in the last place. This `S_exact` we are discussing here is is `100 (exact sum of the original data)/S_pgfplots` where `S_pgfplots` is the `pgfplots` computed sum, hence it is close to `100`.</sub>

<sub>If the re-scaled summands were first truncated to 6 digits, their computed sum could be smaller by at most `4 10^-6=0.04 10^-4` compared to the real one. If we truncate that to 4 digits again we are at most `off by 1` in the last digit compared to the truncation of the exact sum, but with the advantage of knowing we are below the exact result. If the exact result is precisely `100`, then we are almost guaranteed that this procedure will always produce `99.9999` (it could produce `100` only if all ratios were exact at `6 digits` --- well actually that is the case if the `sum` by which we divide is itself exactly `100`).</sub>

Anyway, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{
 my stackbar plot/.style={
             xbar stacked,
             xmin=0,xmax=100,
             symbolic y coords={A,B,C,D,E,F,G},
             ytick=data,
             nodes near coords={xxx},}}

\begin{document}
 \pgfplotstableread[col sep=space]{
 text   --  -    +       ++
 A      0.0 1.7 13.8    84.5
 B      0.0 0.6 20.1    79.3
 C      0.0 1.9 13.2    84.9
 D      0.0 1.6 27.9    70.5
 E      1.3 3.9 19.5    75.3
 F      0.0 1.4 15.0    83.7
 G      0.3 1.7 24.8    73.2
 }\data


\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\thisrow{--}+\thisrow{-}+\thisrow{+}+\thisrow{++}}]{sum}\data %
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/copy=--]{--o}\data
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/copy=-]{-o}\data
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/copy=+]{+o}\data
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/copy=++]{++o}\data
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\xinttheiexpr[6]
   100/\thisrow{sum}*\thisrow{--o}\relax}]{--}\data 
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\xinttheiexpr[6]
   100/\thisrow{sum}*\thisrow{-o}\relax}]{-}\data 
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\xinttheiexpr[6]
   100/\thisrow{sum}*\thisrow{+o}\relax }]{+}\data
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\xinttheiexpr[6]
   100/\thisrow{sum}*\thisrow{++o}\relax }]{++}\data 
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\xinttheiexpr [6]
 \thisrow{--}+\thisrow{-}+\thisrow{+}+\thisrow{++}\relax}]{sumnew}\data
 % better? or even without [4] to get 100 as rounded integer ?
 % \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\xinttheiexpr[4]
 % \thisrow{--}+\thisrow{-}+\thisrow{+}+\thisrow{++}\relax}]{sumnew}\data

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={text,sum}   ,precision=10,columns/text/.style={string type}]\data \quad
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={text,sumnew},precision=10,columns/text/.style={string type}]\data 

%\pgfplotstablesave{\data}{pgfplotstempout.dat}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my stackbar plot]
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{--o},y=text] {\data};
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{-o}, y=text] {\data};
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{+o}, y=text] {\data};
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{++o}, y=text] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my stackbar plot]
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{--},y=text] {\data};
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{-}, y=text] {\data};
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{+}, y=text] {\data};
 \addplot table [x expr = \thisrow{++}, y=text] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: The sumnew is only for diagnostic purpose (I guessed that is does more or less what pgfplots does to decide if a marker is clipped or not). After checking the xint.pdf I have some doubt that `\xinttheiexpr` is the solution. As it rounds it can also round *up*, and so I still can end with a too large sum. What I need it something like "floor to 4 decimal position."

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you can use `\xinttheiexpr [4] trunc(..., 4)\relax` (I need to add rounding modes to the syntax) or directly with macros. `\xintTrunc {4}{more macros}`. I am not sure where you need the floor, if `sumnew` is for diagnostic. With macros for individual entries `\xintRound {6}{\xintDiv {\xintMul {100}{\thisrow{--o}}}{\thisrow{sum}}}`, and a sum truncated to 4 digits `\xintTrunc {4}{\xintSum
  {{\thisrow{--}}{\thisrow{-}}{\thisrow{+}}{\thisrow{++}}}}`  (sorry for many braces... that's the problem of macros compared to expressions). (if you only use macros, `xintfrac` is enough)

Comment: `\xintRound {6}{\xintDiv {\xintE {\thisrow{--o}}{2}}{\thisrow{sum}}}` is more efficient macro than with `\xintMul{100}{...}`.

Comment: I have quite a number of plots, but not so many that it really matters which calculation is more efficient. I do find the trunc version quite readable and so will use it. But \xinttheiexpr [4] trunc(..., 4) looks a bit "doubled", shouldn't `\xinttheexpr trunc(...,5)\relax` be enough to floor the numbers a bit?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Absolutely. I should read the docs ;-) Usually `\xinttheexpr` may output strange things likes `A/B[N]`,  but if the top-most thing is `trunc(foo,d)` then it will just produce the fixed point number with `d` digits after decimal mark, as internally `trunc`  ends up being macro `\xintTrunc` and `\xinttheexpr` will not do any extra formatting on its output.